# Cordova - button for Hold to record audio - sometimes stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

Let me explain it thoroughly. I am building a chat app using Cordova, and I want to do a sound recording function just like in Messenger, where you hold a button, it changes it appearance, then after some time you release the button, and the sound file is sent to the server. I tried to do it, sometimes it works, but sometimes it stops unexpectedly, or sometimes the button's appearance changes to unclicked, when you move your finger one pixel.

- Frameworks I am using: [Onsen UI](https://onsen.io/v2/docs/js.html) and [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Now here is my html of the button

```
<ons-button id="btnRecordSound" modifier="large" disable-auto-styling>Hold to record</ons-button>
```

And here is the javascript

```
let soundRecord = '';
let isRecording = false;

function setRecordSoundButton() {
    $('#btnRecordSound').on('touchstart touchend', (event) => {
        if (event.type == 'touchstart') {
            startSoundRecording();
        } else if (event.type == 'touchend') {
            stopSoundRecording();
        }
    });
}

function startSoundRecording() {
    soundRecord = new Media(/*some file path here*/, () => {
        // success function
    });
    soundRecord.startRecord();
    isRecording = true;
    setTimeout(favoChat.stopSoundRecording, 30000);
}

function stopSoundRecording() {
    if (isRecording) {
        isRecording = false;
        soundRecord.stopRecord();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I rely on touchstart and touchend events to determine when to start and stop it, and there is also a forced setTimeout function that stops the recording at a given time limit.

Is this the best way to visualize the button? I need it to not change appearance when moved just one pixel away from the touch point. If anything, I would like to set some max interval, that when move outside of it, then stop it.
And, are the start and stop functions ok? I need the stop function to be exact.

Comment: I'm not sure if that hepls but you could try event.preventDefault(); in the first line of your event handler.

Comment: You need to clear the `setTimeout` in the `stopSoundRecording` function.

Comment: @Kris where do I do that exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd imagine the reason it *stops unexpectedly* is due to the fact you're not clearing your timeout after setting it.

If you start recording a 20-second audio clip, stop recording and then instantly start recording again there is still a timeout with 10 seconds left on it because it's not been cleared and will run after the 10 seconds.

If you change your code to something like this:

```
let soundRecord = '';
let isRecording = false;
let soundTimeout = null;

function setRecordSoundButton() {
    $('#btnRecordSound').on('touchstart touchend', (event) => {
        if (event.type == 'touchstart') {
            startSoundRecording();
        } else if (event.type == 'touchend') {
            stopSoundRecording();
        }
    });
}

function startSoundRecording() {
    soundRecord = new Media( /*some file path here*/ , () => {
        // success function
    });
    soundRecord.startRecord();
    isRecording = true;
    soundTimeout = setTimeout(favoChat.stopSoundRecording, 30000);
}

function stopSoundRecording() {
    if (isRecording) {
        clearTimeout(soundTimeout);
        isRecording = false;
        soundRecord.stopRecord();
    }
}
```

It should fix that issue.